# crash to perform a popover segue from a ModalView

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, storyboard, popover

I need to open a popover from a subview inside a ModalView. These subviews are added on ModalView at viewDidLoad using [self.storyboard instatiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier]

When I click to open a popover the application exit without any information about the crash.

the sample project with this error can be downloaded here (https://www.dropbox.com/s/mjpaqk6xwt86dbd/PopoverTest.zip)

I´m using xCode 4.3.1 and iOS SDK 5.0 and storybord.

thanks

André

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In viewDidLoad, you're instantiating a bunch of view controllers with `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`, but those aren't retained or referenced anywhere after that.  I'm pretty sure ARC is releasing them for you at the end of viewDidLoad, which is causing the crash.  If it didn't do this, it would be a leak.

One solution would be to store those view controllers in an array, and release it on viewDidUnload.

Comment: thanks zpasternack, it works fine.

here is the new code (https://www.dropbox.com/s/gm23oj1r4jjrn9e/PopoverTestNew.zip)